# Java, 1 try block, 2 different constructors throws same exception, separate?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

In following code, both Scanner and PrintWriter constructor throws FileNotFound-exception.

(PrintWriter throws if e.g. the file is readonly).

I want to make different adjustments depending on whether of the two threw the exception.

How do I accomplish this in a hopefully simple way? Can't find a fitting method in the FileNotFoundException-class.

```
try {
    lineReader = new Scanner( scanFile );
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("ord.txt");

    try { ... }

    finally { 
        lineReader.close(); 
        pw.close();
    }

} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Comment: you could put the printwriter line in another try block inside the first

Comment: You'll have to create two blocks or if you want to add some logic to your exception you can inspect the stacktrace with `e.getStackTrace` and get the last call in the stacktrace. This should return either the scanner call or the printwriter call.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this without changing what you have too much (i.e. no more nested `try`s):

```
boolean success = false;  // <--

try {
    lineReader = new Scanner( scanFile );
    success = true;  // <--
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("ord.txt");

    ...

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    /*
     * If 'success' is false, then Scanner threw the
     * exception, otherwise it was PrintWriter.
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using another try block

```
try {
    lineReader = new Scanner( scanFile );

    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("ord.txt");

        try { ... }

        finally { 
            lineReader.close(); 
        pw.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //thrown by printwriter
    }

} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//thrown by scanner
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this............

```
try
{    
    try {
     lineReader = new Scanner( scanFile );
    :
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }

    try {
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("ord.txt");
     :
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
}
    finally { 
        lineReader.close(); 
        pw.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @arshajii 's code:

```
try {
    lineReader = new Scanner( scanFile );
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("ord.txt");

    ...

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    if(lineReader==null){
       // Reader is at fault
    }else{
       //PrintWriter is at fault
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the obvious double try-catch, you can inspect the stacktrace.

Consider the following example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            maybeThrowAnException1();
            maybeThrowAnException2();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
        }

    }

    private static void maybeThrowAnException1() throws FileNotFoundException{
        if(new Random().nextInt(2) % 2 == 0){
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    private static void maybeThrowAnException2() throws FileNotFoundException{
        if(new Random().nextInt(2) % 2 == 0){
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

This will sometimes print `MaybeThrowAnException1`, sometimes `MaybeThrowAnException2`.
You can change this to `e.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName()` to see if it returns `Scanner` or `PrintWriter` and perform logic based on that result.

Comment: Cheers! Ill go with e.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName()

Comment: This is an extremely hacky approach, and it encourages bad practice. It would be much better to use some kind of boolean flag or use nested `try`s.